# Parse-server multi-tenant

Tags: parse-platform

I'm looking to setup a parse-server instance so that multiple users can have separate logins with separate apps, just like parse currently offers. Does Parse provide an open source implementation of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Parse Dashboard: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard

You can define a configuration file to point multiple parse servers and define multiple user credentials with app access like this:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "serverURL": "https://api.parse.com/1",
      "appId": "myAppId1",
      "masterKey": "myMasterKey",
      "javascriptKey": "myJavascriptKey",
      "restKey": "myRestKey",
      "appName": "My Parse.Com App",
      "production": true
    },
    {
      "serverURL": "http://localhost:1337/parse",
      "appId": "myAppId2",
      "masterKey": "myMasterKey",
      "appName": "My Parse Server App"
    }
  ],
  "users": [
     {
       "user":"user1",
       "pass":"pass1",
       "apps": [{"appId1": "myAppId1"}, {"appId2": "myAppId2"}]
     },
     {
       "user":"user2",
       "pass":"pass2",
       "apps": [{"appId1": "myAppId1"}]
     }  
  ]
}
```